# jQuery tabs sort

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery tabs, and trying to save the positions of the Tabs (and of course the content in the tabs). Could you please suggest me a way to do the same?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the order is defined by the element position in html, not the tabs plugin, not jquery, not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can set which tab is active by using the selected property

```
$('.selector').tabs({ selected: 3 });
```

You'll also need a way of storing which tab is active. For that we have the [select event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select), you can listen for the select event, and then on the callback either send an Ajax call back to the server with the information (which tab is active), or create a cookie where you store the same information.

Then when the page loads you just need to either get that information from the server or the cookie, and use the [select property](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected) to set the active tab.

Comment: We can save the active tabs by using selected property, but how can we decide/save the order of the tabs?

Comment: Either in a cookie or on the server. Use the select event (which gets triggered every time the selected tab changes) to call a callback function that creates/updates the cookie, or sends the data back to the server with Ajax.